# Set text-property a buffer text automatically

Tags: text-properties

I use Julia REPL, Singular or some other math software in my emacs.
In every case, I have a buffer (*julia* or *Singular*,...) synchronise with some running process.
The last line of this buffer is where I introduce the commands to execute.
This last line is something like

```
julia >
```

or

```
>
```

So, I would like to add the property `cursor-intangible` to this text, since I will never edit it and it would be much more similar to an actual terminal.
I know the commands `add-text-property` and so on, but I would like something that works automatically every time that the buffer changes.
Does it exists? It would be something similar to `font-lock` but for properties.

Comment: Whoever writes up the answer would need to examine the code that generates the prompt `julia >` and `>` to see if *some* text property support is built-in (e.g., a color or something like that), or whether it needs to be added contemporaneously when the prompt is generated, or perhaps a solution has already been written up somewhere on the internet.  Rather than having everyone Google the terms *Julia REPL Emacs*, perhaps you can provide a link to the source code that you are using ...

Comment: For `julia` I use ess (emacs speaks statistics) and `julia-mode` and for Singular https://github.com/Singular/Sources/tree/spielwiese/emacs

Comment: But that would be an inconvenient solution, I am looking for a solution for all math software. Is not there some hook, function... something that adds/sets text properties every time a buffer is modified? Something like `font-lock-add-keywords`

Comment: Here is a link to the manual describing the standard hooks:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Standard-Hooks.html  One hook on the list that stands out is the `after-change-functions` hook ... "*List of functions to call after each text change....*".  There may be other hooks on the list that could be of assistance.

Comment: Does setting `comint-prompt-read-only` to `t` work? Otherwise, I believe that you can adapt line 2113 to 2124 in https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/comint.el to get what you want (assuming that the REPL's are powered by comint).

Comment: It partially works, now I cannot edit the prompt but the cursor still moves into it, for example with `move-beginning-of-line`. I will try to modify lines 2113--2124, that will work for every mode using `comint`

Answer (score 1):

Solution proposed by @T.Verron works, nevertheless sadly `singular-interactive-mode` do not use `comint`. So, here I propose another solution following @lawist suggestion. This code produces a function `brust-math-software-hookfun-to-intangify-prompt`, which adds buffer-locally a function to `after-change-functions` which properly properties the prompt accordingly to the list `brust-math-software-buffers-prompts`.
You only need to add such a function to the hook of your mode.
And to add new languages you just need to update the list of buffers-prompts.

```
    (defvar brust-math-software-buffers-prompts
      '(("*julia*"    . "^julia>")
        ("*singular*" . "^>"))
      "List of cons with buffer names runing some math software and a regex for its promp string")

    (defun brust-math-software-intangify-buffer-text (-regexp beg end)
      "Set cursor-intangible property to all buffer text maching regular expresion `-regexp` between `beg` and  `end`"
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char beg)
        (save-match-data
          (while (re-search-forward -regexp end t)
            (add-text-properties (1- (match-beginning 0)) (match-end 0) '(cursor-intangible t rear-nonsticky nil))))))

    (defun brust-math-software-intangify-cursor-on-prompt (beg end length)
      "Set cursor-intangible in math software buffers prompts"
      (let ((-prompt (cdr (assoc (buffer-name) brust-math-software-buffers-prompts))))
        (when -prompt
          (brust-math-software-intangify-buffer-text -prompt beg end))))

    (defun brust-math-software-hookfun-to-intangify-prompt nil
      (cursor-intangible-mode 1)
      (add-hook 'after-change-functions #'brust-math-software-intangify-cursor-on-prompt nil t))
```

I have no idea why, but there is some incompatibility between properties `cursor-intangible` and `rear-nonsticky`. 
So, the lines 2113--2124 from @T.Verron answer would be:

```
      (add-text-properties prompt-start (point)
                           '(cursor-intangible t rear-nonsticky nil read-only t front-sticky (read-only)))))
```